# Thread Cancellation Surprise in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, cancellation-token

I recently had to respond to a production incident where a background thread that executed some code on a loop had stopped executing, but a related thread was continuing to do it's job, in spite of the second thread being explicitly cancelled.

As I read the code, I believe that because of the finally statement (See below) the second thread should have been cancelled and thus further executions stopped. It's worth noting, that the code in the implementation of IBackgroundJob failed with a TaskCancelledException, due to timeouts of > 100 seconds (default for Http I believe).

Can anyone clarify why, when the code exits the inner while loop (either because of cancellation token source state or an exception), the executing code on the second thread (KeepRenewingLock) would continue to run? Would the leaseCancellation?.Cancel() not cancel the token being used by the KeepRenewingLock and thus prevent further lock renewals (incidentally, the lock item behind the scenes continued to be renewed. We could see this from the timestamps on the lock item)

```
public class Leasing
{
    private Task _task;
    private readonly CancellationTokenSource _cts;
    private readonly IBackgroundJob _backgroundJob;

    public Leasing(IBackgroundJob backgroundJob)
    {
        _backgroundJob = backgroundJob; 
        _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    }
    
    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _task = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await RunAsync(_cts.Token);
        }, cancellationToken);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private async Task RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            CancellationTokenSource leaseCancellation = null;

            try
            {
                leaseCancellation = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(cancellationToken);
                var maintainLockTask = Task.Run(() => KeepRenewingLock(leaseCancellation.Token), leaseCancellation.Token);
                
                while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested && !maintainLockTask.IsCompleted)
                {
                    await RunBackgroundJobSafely(cancellationToken);

                    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2), cancellationToken);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //code to log error
            }
            finally
            {
                leaseCancellation?.Cancel();
                leaseCancellation?.Dispose(); 
            }
        }
    }

    private async Task RunBackgroundJobSafely(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        try
        {
            await _backgroundJob.ExecuteAsync(cancellationToken);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) when (!_cts.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            //log error
        }
    }

    private void KeepRenewingLock(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        try
        {
            while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                //task delay here
                //code to renew lease
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            //code to log error
        }
    }
}

public interface IBackgroundJob
{
    Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken);
}
```

Comment: ```_task = Task.Run(async () => { await RunAsync(_cts.Token); }, cancellationToken);``` I'm not sure why this doesn't also use a linked token source, but that certainly seems to be problematic.

Comment: What does the `catch` block in `RunBackgroundJobSafely` do exactly? Because if it doesn't (re)throw the exception then you end up in an infinite inner loop, and the code never reaches `?.Cancel()` call. This would contradict your "stopped executing" claim, however, how exactly you know that the code stopped executing? You have 2min delays here, maybe the code was still running but was just force killed during the delay?

Comment: You may want to clean up your nomenclature. You don't _cancel a thread_, you _cancel a task_.  Now, all your calls to `Task.Run` will result in a task running on a thread in the threadpool, but those threads are never "cancelled" (they will live beyond the life of the task (cancelled or not)

Comment: Thanks all. Appreciate the input and points on nomenclature. Re the catch block in the RunBackgroundJobSafely function, it doesn't throw. It just logs. But, the inner while loop definitely exited during the incident. We could see regular activity in our azure app insights telemetry to see the background job was running. But stopped at the point the task was cancelled (TaskCancelledException). Yet the lease kept renewing. I'd expect the finally block to prevent the KeepRenewingLock function from succeeding as the leaseCancellation token is canelled and KeepRenewingLock checks each execution.

Comment: @TimButterfield what exactly is getting cancelled? You pass `cancellationToken` to the top `Task.Run()` call, but you actually call `RunAsync` with `_cts.Token`. Two unrelated tokens. I don't see code that ever cancels `_cts`, and so how exactly you know that the inner loop ever exits? What is the purpose of `_cts` anyway? As David L mentioned: this looks very problematic. I think the devil is in the details here. Without commented out pieces it is hard to tell what exactly happens in your code.

Comment: All, thank you for the feedback. And I appreciate it's all a bit cryptic without the body of the code executing with in each block. I've also been lazy and not given the fill picture, so apologies for that. I neglected (my mistake) to include a StopAsync function which calls  _cts.Cancel(); and not mentioned that the class implements IHostedService. I'll got back and update. Appreciate all the input. I didn't write the code and only came across when having to support a system using it, but didn't want my interpretation of the code to result in me missing something fundamental. Thanks again.

Comment: I've now put missing log statements in place to help, should this occur again, but without extra logging our present level of logging/tracing doesn't allow us to draw a decisive conclusion as to what exactly happened. Once again apologies for vague code example. I had to leave out some details but that makes it much harder to reason about.